# When we use '..., let alone...' why don't we put the more general statement last

Tags: terminology

"I never thought I'd be in a car, let alone drive one." Is a correct usage of 'let alone', right?

But wouldn't it make more sense to say the reverse? : "I never though I'd drive a car, let alone be in one."

I'm interpreting 'let alone' as implying lesser value in comparison; since driving would be a more complicated scenario as it includes being in one. So, if you're letting something alone, shouldn't it be the less complex one?

Comment: It is possible to be in a car without driving it, but not *vice versa*.

Answer (score 4):

You've got it backwards. *Let alone* designates a **less likely** eventuality; compare the equivalent expression *much less*. You may paraphrase:

> I previously regarded it as unlikely that I should ever be in a car; I regarded it as even less likely that I should ever drive one.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, the answer to which can get complicated very quickly, though we scarcely give it a thought when we use the locution "let alone."

***Laying the Foundation***

"Being in a car" seems like an easy thing to do. To the experienced driver, driving a car also seems easy to do. The latter, however, involves much more than simply being a passenger in a car.

Your sentence features a person who at one time didn't even want to BE in a car but is now not only IN a car but is DRIVING the car. That's why the sentence is constructed the way it is. It's a **variation** on "*argumentum a minore ad maius*" (i.e., the argument from the lesser to the greater).

Accordingly, if someone has the attitude "I neither want to be in a car nor do I want to drive one," and that someone one day finds himself not only being *in* a car but also *driving* one, then logic dictates the following (where X is being in a car and Y is driving a car):

> If X, which is relatively easy to do but despite its easiness is not likely to be done, then Y, which is a good bit harder to do than X, is even less likely to be done.

***In Other Words***

Call the logic the "how much more" argument, if you like. It's quite commonplace in everyday conversations.

Let's say a person hates asparagus with a passion! He would rather eat maggot-infested meat than have just one bite of asparagus. What do you think the chances are of this person eating a *plateful* of asparagus (with asparagus cream sauce on top!)? Slim to none, right?

What if the asparagus hater had a change of heart and on a dare tasted a head of asparagus (the best part, by the way, IMHO) drenched in butter with a touch of salt. He bites, he chews, he swallows, he smiles. As was said of "Mikey" in the [Life cereal commercial](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=the%20commercial%20about%20life%20cereal%20in%20which%20kids%20give%20the%20cereal%20to%20timmy%20because%20he%20eats%20everything.&view=detail&mid=77E9EBDFD618B3361E2577E9EBDFD618B3361E25&FORM=VIRE), "He likes it!"

So it is with the "how much more" argument.

Jesus used this kind of reasoning in the Sermon on the Mount. In his teaching on God's provision of life's basic necessities (food and clothes, mostly), he turned his hearers' attention to the birds of the air and the flowers of the field.

> If the birds,

Jesus reasoned,

> are cared for and fed by God, and the flowers without even thinking about it are dressed in splendor by God's own design, how much more will he feed and clothe his children who are more precious than birds and flowers.

***Can Something Be Truer Than Something Else Which Is True?***

Well, in a word, yes (sort of). In the "much less" locution, the truth of "not likely" is placed before the *truer* "even less likely" for purposes of contrast.

When comparing "not likely being *in a car*" and "actually *driving a car*," the latter is much less likely than the former. Substituting a different locution, you could say,

> Since I truly thought I would never even *sit* in a car, *how much more* would I think it true I would never *drive* a car.

***Conclusion***

Where my answer breaks down just a little bit is that "how much more" and "let alone" do not seem fungible. I realize that, and frankly I am not sure how to solve that problem. Like you, the logic of the "let alone" locution puzzles me. My advice (both to me and you), find and use another locution which makes more sense to you!